# Replacing '?' in a dataframe in R with ZEROs in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help with replacing '?' on my data frame with Zeros in R language.

any help will be highly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
  A=c(1,"?",3),
  B=c(1:3),
  C=c("a", "b", "?")
)

df <- apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
  x[x == "?"] <- 0
  x
})
as.data.frame(df)
#   A B C
# 1 1 1 a
# 2 0 2 b
# 3 3 3 0
```

Comment: `df[ df == "?" ] <- 0` should work, too.

Comment: Thanks all. it worked.

Comment: `df[ df == "?" ] <- 0` not work with factors without zero. `invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: You could convert them into character and apply what @zx8754 has suggested. Seems simpler.